# How to calculate polyline azimuth or polyline direction?

Tags: arcpy

I am looking for a Python code block to calculate azimuth per each polyline feature.
So far I have been able to use the following Python code to calculate bearing:

```
180  + math.atan2(( !Shape.firstpoint.X! - !Shape.lastpoint.X! ),
(!Shape.firstpoint.Y! - !Shape.lastpoint.Y! ) ) * (180 / math.pi)
```

However bearing is not sufficient for me as I am looking to ultimately find line directions which can be detected by caclulating an azimuth.

Comment: Just curious, what does the '180 +' do here?

Answer (score 5):

Not in arcpy but the math is pretty clear. From Bill Huber in 2004.

[How do I compute azimuth for line segment and add to attribute table](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=38&t=117018&g=1#335748)

```
z = (-y/x).ATan.AsDegrees
if (x < 0) then z = z+180 end ' Adjust ATan in quadrants II and III
z = -(z + 180 mod 360 - 180)  ' Convert to the range -180..180
```